# Azure RM Template AutomationRunbookServiceUriIsNotValid

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-rm

I need to deploy a resource of type "microsoft.insights/actionGroups" with ARM Template and I am stuck on a problem. My Template :

```
{
     "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
     "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
     "location": "Global",
     "name": "[variables('ActionGroupName')]",
     "tags": {
        "displayName": "MyActionGroupName"
     },
     "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "variables('ActionGroupShortName')",
        "enabled": true,
        "automationRunbookReceivers": [
           {
              "name": "MyRunbookRecieverName",
              "automationAccountId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('AzureTelemetryName'))]",
              "runbookName": "MyRunbook",
              "webhookResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks', parameters('AzureAutomationName'), 'WebHookName')]",
              "isGlobalRunbook": false
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

But when I try to deploy I get this error:

> New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 08:39:52 - Resource microsoft.insights/actionGroups 'ActionGroupName' failed with message '{
>     "Code": "AutomationRunbookServiceUriIsNotValid",
>     "Message": "AutomationRunbookServiceUriIsNotValid"

I look over [template definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2019-06-01/actiongroups), and it is mentioned that `WebhookReceiver.identifierUri` is not mandatory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `automationRunbookReceivers`, why you say about `identifierUri` in `WebhookReceiver`? may be should be `serviceUri` in `automationRunbookReceivers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue with the template, I add the `serviceUri` in the `automationRunbookReceivers`, then it works fine. You can  refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#creating-a-webhook) to create the webhook.

```
 "automationRunbookReceivers": [
           {
              "name": "MyRunbookRecieverName",
              "automationAccountId": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('AzureTelemetryName'))]",
              "runbookName": "MyRunbook",
              "webhookResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/webhooks', parameters('AzureAutomationName'), 'WebHookName')]",
              "isGlobalRunbook": false,
              "serviceUri":"https://s16events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
           }
        ]
```

---

To the `serviceUri` is not required issue, I am not sure if there is some mistake of the doc, just some test result for you to refer.(If I do something wrong, please correct me.)

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/2019-06-01/actiongroups#automationrunbookreceiver-object), it appears like below. The `name` is `No` required, but if I deploy without it, I get the `AutomationRunbookReceiverNameIsNullOrEmpty` error. The `useCommonAlertSchema` is required, but if I deploy withou it, I will get no error. The same thing happens to the `serviceUri`.

[image]

Comment: How can I refer my webhook if I created it with ARM Template ? The Uri is not visible anywhere in the process ?

Comment: P.S. Thank you for the response is very clear. It seem to have a gap between doc and reality.

Comment: @Francis yes, the url is not visible after creating it, we could just save it when creating.